# Pull full URL parameter that contains a Hash Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-parameters

I have a URL that looks like so:

```
example.com/puppy-reservation?puppy=Bitzy's Female #1
```

I need to read the entire URL parameter. I tried using the following script:

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results==null){
       return null;
    }
    else{
       return results[1] || 0;
    }
}

console.log(decodeURIComponent($.urlParam('puppy')));
```

When this runs it gives me `Bitzy's Female`.

How do I modify the script to read the entire URL parameter? IE: `Bitzy's Female #1`

To explain a bit further. My CMS is outputting the name of a database entry. In this case it is `Bitzy's Female #1`. This is the way it is entered into the CMS. On a page a person can click the URL that you see above: `example.com/puppy-reservation?puppy=Bitzy's Female #1`

When the page loads I read the URL parameter and insert the name into a few fields on the page. This is why I need to read the full parameter, including the hash tag, so it displays correctly on the page.

Comment: Remove `#` from the negating character set?

Comment: @hjpotter92 - Possibly but I am looking for a way to have it there if at all possible.

Comment: Can you explain what you meant? If you want to match the parameter until the end of string, try `(.+?(?:&|$))`

Comment: `#1` isn't considered part of a url query param because it is a url hash and browsers will read it as such. If it's not intended to be a url hash then it should be properly encoded

Comment: @hjpotter92 - That worked. Please post an answer so I can give credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credit for this answer goes to @hjpotter92. I am posting it here since he left it in a comment.

In my code I had the following line:

```
var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
```

If I changed `=([^&#]*)')` to `=(.+?(?:&|$))')` it worked.

Full code:

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=(.+?(?:&|$))').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results==null){
       return null;
    }
    else{
       return results[1] || 0;
    }
}

console.log(decodeURIComponent($.urlParam('puppy')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
var url = window.location.href;
url = encodeURIComponent(url).split(encodeURIComponent('?'))[1];
var obj = {};
if (url) {
    url = url.split(encodeURIComponent('&'));
    for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
       var param = url[i].split(encodeURIComponent('='));
       obj[decodeURIComponent(param[0])] = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
    }
}
console.log(obj);
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xvgs6r38/3/